# anchor tikz at the left margin

Tags: tikz-pgf, margins

I would like to place a tikz picture at the left margin location of the current line. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\status}[1]{\tikz[overlay]{\node [left=3cm] {\bf#1};}}
    in (here)\status{??} the beginning of the line\\
    towards the middle of end of line (here)\status{?!}
\end{document}
```

which, as expected, produces

[image]

I know that there is `at (current page.west)` that I can use, but this doesn't seem to work (and isn't precisely what I want) and I couldn't find the correct fix in the documentation/elsewhere. Also, I know that there's a `todos` package which has similar functionallity but I really just need this simple bit only.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's the [`tikzpagenodes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzpagenodes) package which offers `current page text area` anchors:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcounter{tmp}
\newcommand\status[1]{%
  \stepcounter{tmp}%
  \tikzmark{start-\thetmp}%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay,baseline=(sta.base)]
    {\node[anchor=east] at (current page text area.west|-{pic cs:start-\thetmp})
    (sta) {\textbf{#1}};}%
}
\begin{document}

test\status{ready!}

test\status{to do!}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without `tikzpagenodes` you need to anchor at the x-coordinate of `current page west`and then shift by an amount `\oddsidemargin+\hoffset+1in`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}

\newcounter{tmp}
\newcommand\status[1]{%
  \stepcounter{tmp}%
  \tikzmark{start-\thetmp}%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay,baseline=(sta.base)]
    {\node[anchor=east] at 
    ( $ (current page.west|-{pic cs:start-\thetmp}) + (\oddsidemargin+\hoffset+1in,0) $ )
    (sta) {\textbf{#1}};}%
}
\begin{document}

test\status{ready!}

test\status{to do!}

\end{document}
```

Comment: not as simple as wanted (hoped tikz would provide `(page.west+document.margin,current.y)`) or something like that but this certainly does what I want, so thanks!

Comment: @r0fg1 You're welcome! I updated my answer with an option not involving `tikzpagenodes`.